# Conflicting values for equivalent expressions of $\tan(\arccos{x})$

Tags: calculus

Since $$\tan{x}=\sqrt{\sec^2x-1}$$ we can substitute $x=\arccos\theta$ to get $$\tan(\arccos\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{cos^2(\arccos\theta)}-1}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\theta^2}-1}$$
If we multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$

However, the values of the following integrals are not equivalent

$$\int^{-\frac{1}{2}}_{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\,dx\neq \int^{-\frac{1}{2}}_{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\,dx$$
via desmos, we get 0.45093249314 and −0.45093249314. How can this be?

Comment: Taking the $\theta^2$ outside of the squareroot gives $|\theta|$, not $\theta$. This is, $\sqrt(x^2)=|x|$, which is equal to $x$ only for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Also, when $-1 \le \theta < 0$, $\frac \pi 2 < \arccos\theta \le \pi$. In that interval, $\tan (\arccos \theta)$ is negative, so

$$\tan  x = -\sqrt{\sec^2 x - 1}$$

Not sure whether this is related to the later integration though.